# JQuery Radial Plot with zooming

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

Does anyone know of a JQuery Radial chart that also has zooming functionality.

RGraph http://www.rgraph.net/examples/rscatter.html does not have zooming functionality.
JqPlot has zooming but does not have radial chart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)?

Also, [InfoVis](http://thejit.org/demos/) but it's not using jQuery.